# Hadoop Map Reduce - Nested loops on Iterable<Text> values in reduce ignore Text result when writing them into the context

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

I'm new with hadoop and I was trying to run a map reduce on a simple input file (See example).
I've tried to make some kind of Cartesian product from a list of attributes using two for loops and for some reason the result value which I got was always empty.
I've tried to jiggle with it and eventually it worked only if I set the result Text while iterating over it (I know, that sounds weird to me too).
I would appreciate if you can help me to understand the problem, probablyl something I do wrong.

This is the input file which I have.

```
A 1
B 2
C 1
D 2
C 2
E 1
```

I would want to get the following output:

```
1 A-C, A-E, C-E
2 B-C, B-D, C-D
```

So I tried to implement the following map reduce class:
    public class DigitToPairOfLetters {

```
    public static class TokenizerMapper
            extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text digit = new Text();
        private Text letter = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                letter.set(itr.nextToken());
                digit.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(digit, letter);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class DigitToLetterReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text result = new Text();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Text value :values) {
                valuesList.add(value.toString());
            }
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0; i<valuesList.size(); i++) {
                for (int j=i+1; j<valuesList.size(); j++) {
                    builder.append(valuesList.get(i)).append(" 
").append(valuesList.get(j)).append(",");
                }
            }
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "digit to letter");
        job.setJarByClass(DigitToPairOfLetters.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(DigitToLetterReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(DigitToLetterReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

but this code will provide me the following output of empty lists:

```
1
2
```

When I added set for result in the for loops it seems to work:
    public class DigitToPairOfLetters {

```
    public static class TokenizerMapper
            extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text digit = new Text();
        private Text letter = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                letter.set(itr.nextToken());
                digit.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(digit, letter);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class DigitToLetterReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text result = new Text();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Text value :values) {
                valuesList.add(value.toString());
                // TODO: We set the valuesList in the result since otherwise the 
hadoop process will ignore the values
                // in it.
                result.set(valuesList.toString());
            }
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0; i<valuesList.size(); i++) {
                for (int j=i+1; j<valuesList.size(); j++) {
                    builder.append(valuesList.get(i)).append(" 
").append(valuesList.get(j)).append(",");
                    // TODO: We set the builder every iteration in the loop since otherwise the hadoop process will
                    // ignore the values
                    result.set(builder.toString());
                }
            }
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "digit to letter");
        job.setJarByClass(DigitToPairOfLetters.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(DigitToLetterReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(DigitToLetterReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

This will give me the following result:

```
1   [A C,A E,C E]
2   [B C,B D,C D]
```

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach seems to be fine, you just need to add this line:

```
result.set(builder.toString());
```

before

```
context.write(key, result);
```

Just like you did in the second function.

Context.write flushes the output and since result is just an empty object nothing is passed as the value, only the key is passed. So before passing you need to set the value (A-E, etc) into the result.

Comment: Also no need to add, result.set(valuesList.toString());
Only result.set(builder.toString()); will work

Comment: I've added the reseult set only at the end as suggested like so:
    context.write(key, result);
    result.set(builder.toString());
and removed all the result.set(..) commands which I've added in the second try but I still get empty lists.

Comment: Edited my answer. The result.set(builder.toString()); needs to go before context.write(key, result);